# How do I build a new SDNode in llvm?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to add support to a new arch in llvm backend (llc). However I have found it diffcult to add a new SDNode that has 2 results. I saw in the sparc arch that UMUL/SMUL has 2 results (the second is Y) so they defined:

```
let Defs = [Y] in {
  defm UMUL : ...
  defm SMUL : ...
}
```

and

```
let Uses = [Y], ... in
  def RDY : ...
```

and in the select function it looks like that :

```
 SDNode *Mul = CurDAG->getMachineNode(Opcode, dl, MVT::i32, MVT::Glue,
                                     MulLHS, MulRHS);
// The high part is in the Y register.
return CurDAG->SelectNodeTo(N, SP::RDY, MVT::i32, SDValue(Mul, 1));
```

so they are using result 1 - I think is the Y...

---

in my case I have a instruction that affect a cc bit.
So I tried to use the same way. I defined in the Xinstr:

```
def SUBCri : ...>{
  let Defs = [CRZ];
}
```

.
.

```
let Uses = [CRZ] in {
  def BRC_Z : ... (outs), (ins target:$dst),
}
```

and in the select function :

```
    SDVTList VTs = CurDAG->getVTList(MVT::i32, MVT::Glue);
    SDNode * CondCode = CurDAG->getMachineNode(X::SUBCri, dl, VTs, ops);
    SDNode * ResNode = CurDAG->SelectNodeTo(Node, X::BRC_Z, MVT::Other, Dst,
            SDValue(CondCode, 1));
```

but I get the next error :

```
Assertion `NumMIOperands >= II.getNumOperands() && NumMIOperands <= II.getNumOperands() + II.getNumImplicitDefs() + NumImpUses && "#operands for dag node doesn't match .td file!"' failed.
```

so my question is :

1. what is the right way to define a SDNode ?
2. what SDVTList VTs means ? Is it the results ? what is the order of the (SDVTList VTs) means ?
3. what are the OpsArray ? is it the inputs ? what is the right order to insert the input ? I saw that in "countOperands" function they check to see if the last one is glue. what does it means the glue is last ? in the same function they check to see if MVT::Other is also exist ? what does it means ?
4. and finally - what am I doing wrong ? why can't I get the second result ? why am I getting this error all the time ?

Answer (score 6):

This should really be a comment, but I have no rep. Some hints that may hopefully help:

- VT stands for ValueType. LLVM needs to know the type(s) of the return values of each SDNode. By passing VTs into getMachineNode, you create a new SDNode that returns as many values as there are in the SDVTList, with the specified types.
- "Glue" is a special ValueType that doesn't actually hold a value. It's just used to ensure that two glued SDNodes don't get separated when instruction scheduling happens.
- "ops" are indeed the incoming inputs.
- The order of inputs and return values should be exactly the order specified in TableGen.
- I'm not sure about this, but I don't think Defs are turned into implicit return values. You might have to manually create a CopyFromReg node, to grab the register that is written to.
- MVT::Other represents a "chain", a way to ensure that instructions with side effects are not reordered relative to each other.

Do read the doxygen docs, they're fairly good at explaining the individual functions (even if a bit lacking in the bigger-picture).

Try starting here: http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1SelectionDAG.html